# How to Display data from a table into form inputs with php(full/exact description down)

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

so the question is why i am getting only the first row of data even by clicking the edit button of the second line while the same request result diplayed the data correctly into my html table rows.
my objective is to display the same data i got in a html table row into a popup form inputs, then edit/update the same data and send the new version of data again into database....any Help or even an idea would be great and thanks in advance.

[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRzaX.png)

```
<?php
$host = "localhost"; //IP of your database
$userName = "root"; //Username for database login
$userPass = ""; //Password associated with the username
$database = "database_name"; //Your database name
$connectQuery = mysqli_connect($host,$userName,$userPass,$database);
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
}else{
    $selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM `table_name` ORDER BY `ID` ASC";
    $result = mysqli_query($connectQuery,$selectQuery);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
  }else{
        $msg = "No Record found";
    }
}?>
<!-- of course starting by a while loop  -->
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){?>
<!-- this how i displayed the data in a table row -->
<td><?php echo $row['row_name'];?></td>
<!-- that's how i displayed the data in a pop-up form inputs -->
 <input type="number" value="<?php echo $row['row_name'];?>">
```

Comment: Please note that those lines are just some sequences and the most important ones related with my problem/question

Answer (score 0):

Is this the whole code?
Because it seems that the closing curly bracket are missing from the while.

I think, you can make some improvement (of course these are just ideas) :

Use PDO :
So you while be able to display the errors and manage your DB in OOP : https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

```
<?php
// DbConnection.php
class DbConnection {

    static function connect() {
        try {
            $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname", "user", "pass");
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            die("Erreur :" . $e->getMessage());
        }
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $pdo->exec("SET NAMES UTF8");
        return $pdo;
    }
}
```

Then you can include or require the the file and call it

```
DbConnection::connect();
```

When you want to use it :

```
<?php
// controller
require = 'DbConnection.php'
$pdo = DbConnection::connect();

$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `table_name` ORDER BY `ID` ASC");
$query->execute();

$rows = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Use foreach :
It while be more easy if you fetch all to use on an array, you can do it like this

```
// view or HTML file
<?php foreach ($rows as $row): ?>
    <!-- this how i displayed the data in a table row -->
    <td><?= $row['row_name'];?></td>
    <!-- that's how i displayed the data in a pop-up form inputs -->
    <input type="number" value="<?= $row['row_name'];?>">
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

To know that `<?php echo ... ?>` is equal to `<?= ... ?>`

I hope that this will help to resolve your problem and that my answer is not off the mark.

*ps: do not hesitate to correct me if you find an error or other.*

Comment: thank you for your comment,first of all the lines i've posted are just some sequences of my code(my whole code is 1000 Line) that are logically related with the problem i am facing and by the way ijust tried your modifications and the same problem is still here (NOTE :not error!)

Comment: Yeah i understand, but it will be a little difficult to provide an answer without the code. Maybe if you provide more details, there will be someone helping with more efficiency.

Comment: hello,sorry for replying back too late,i already solved it by myself and thank you so much for your help i really appreciate it .stay safe!

Comment: hi, no problem, you are welcome, stay safe !